# Broadcast receivers on reboot?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I need to write data in to a file ,when system reboots not on boot complete.
i am using broadcast receiver "android.intent.action.REBOOT" Below is my code and manifest files

```
public class broadcastreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 Log.i("LOG_TAG","rebooted"); 
}
```

manifest file:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
<activity android:name=".broadcast"
android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<receiver android:name="com.example.broadcastreceiver.broadcastreceiver"
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="true"
android:permission="android.permission.REBOOT">
<intent-filter>    
<action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
</application>
```

but i am not able to write even a log when reboots.
note:i donot want to use Bootcompleted action in broadcast receiver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see why you don't want to use BootCompleted, could you provide your reasons?

There is no other action that will alert your broadcast receiver of the boot. You will have to use BootCompleted.

As a note, I hope you are registering you BroadcastReceiver with the context (since you didn't include that code). If you're not using BootComplete, I don't know what action you've registered to expect your above code to execute.

Comment: I need to maintain to receivers one for reboot and one for bootcompleted .i went through broadcast recivers from android.developers.com which suggest it is possible using using Reboot action.

Comment: +1 for answer. You should use BootCompleted if you want to catch the log ouput

Comment: since "android.intent.action.REBOOT" is used by system only it cannot be used in side user application.we need to sign the apk with the platform key.i decided to use boot_completed..thanks every one

Answer (score 0):

Add this, to me work, but on new devices, there are no testing.
For example in the recent nexus not working.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```