# how to upload data through services even after switch off then on android phone

Tags: android

I want to upload some data using web services, I have created a service, but when phone is switch off services are getting kill and data are not uploaded, please guide me on how to create a service which run even after switch of and on android, and will they persist data which is passed in intent to start service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Broadcast Receiver on reboot. Then re-start your background server.

see this question [Broadcast receivers on reboot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736187/broadcast-receivers-on-reboot)

Comment: Please can you write an example, as i have done so much RND, I got confuse. I feel like tossing my self between services, broadcast receiver and pending intent